# Smoke Generation "Unpaired" from Object / Broken Quick Effect Smoke

Tags: eevee-render-engine, smoke-simulation, effects

So I am trying to use blenders quick effect smoke but I am stopped every time I try because the smoke gen isn't sticking with the object I am using. I have tried following tutorials, but this doesn't happen in their videos. I also haven't been able to find evidence of this anywhere online. What is going on?

Videos:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XH8H9ozSjPsX8_aCMUjrQt17_6WLzw6J?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please include some screenshots [or gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/963/5705) of your issue in your post?  We like to keep things such that readers can understand your issue without having to go elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least three choices when blender becomes stubborn in cleaning up its cache:

1. Go to the (Domain) folder with the particle cache and delete all the subfolders to clean up:

[image]

2. Coax a cache clear by changing a Domain parameter (like Resolution Divisions) and then change it back.
3. Change the simulation cache setting to Type = Modular, then it will be easier to "Bake", "Free", "Resume" (from an interrupted simulation if you hit ESCape

[image]

And yes, you have my sympathies that many things in blender can be a bit quirky and frustrating at times!